# Replacing or modifying scroll bar so it is always visible on MacOS

Tags: html, css, macos, scroll, scrollbar

I didn't know this was an option until my boss was saying it wasn't working for his computer, but all Macs have this option to show scrollbars turned off by default.

[image]

I was messing around with a load of different things with overflow in CSS but there seems to be no way to get around this.

I was wondering if anybody else has had this issue or if there is something that can be done about it. Or will I actually have to go into JavaScript and add arrows to make my own fake scrollbar that isn't a scrollbar for everything on my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some plugin like [jquery.scrollbar](https://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/) or [perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar) to make things easy.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I will try do some testing with this.

Comment: In the end I didn't go with either of these options, I used a modified version of this http://jsfiddle.net/Lpjj3n1e/211/ but am accepting your answer anyway